# Does the representation of the group also follow the properties of the group?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Consider the finite group $\mathbb{Z}_2$ with two elements $\{e,g_1\}$ with $g_1^2=e$. We have been told in the class that there is a trivial representation of this group in which we have
$$e\rightarrow 1\ \ \ \&\ \ \ g_1\rightarrow 1.$$
There is also a non-trivial representation in which
$$e\rightarrow 1\ \ \ \&\ \ \ g_1\rightarrow -1.$$
Now, I don't understand the trivial representation. Since in that both the elements are the same, but isn't in the group the two elements can't be the same? Further, the identity element is also not unique, How did this come about?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 1):

The question can be answered by using the definition of a representation.

The key property of a representation $g\rightarrow L(g)$ is the following (rep(resentation) property):

$$\text{if}\quad g_1 \rightarrow L(g_1) \quad\text{and}\quad g_2 \rightarrow L(g_2)\quad\text{then}\quad g_1g_2 \rightarrow L(g_1)L(g_2)$$

We are going to check it for the trivial representation of $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

In this case $g_2=e$. Apparently $e$ is the unit element of the group $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Therefore $g_1e = g_1$. Therefore

$g_1 = g_1 e \stackrel{\text{rep property}}{\longrightarrow} L(g_1)L(e) = -1$.

The product of group elements is mapped on the product of the representations. So for the trivial representation the rep property is fulfilled.

We should it check also for other combinations as $g_1^2$ and $e^2$, but the rule to be applied is obvious. A last important detail is that is needed for a representation is that the unit element of the group should be mapped on the identity of the representation. This is also fulfilled:

$e\rightarrow 1$

The trivial representation seems to be superfluous, but it isn't. Actually it is very important.

Imagine a scalar under the effect of rotation. It is invariant. So the rotation group elements act on the scalar in the trivial representation.

Or the group SU(2) which reflects an internal symmetry of the electro-weak interaction   acts on the pair $(\nu_{eL}, e_L)^T$   (the first a left-handed neutrino and the second a left-handed electron)   with a full-fledged SU(2) matrix$\neq 1$, whereas on the right-handed electron $e_R$ it has no effect at all. The effect of SU(2) on the right-handed electron is that of a trivial representation (for simplicity all involved particles are assumed to be massless).

Comment: There mapping in which both elements are mapped to zero also satisfies the property. Is it also a representation?

Comment: No. To each group element there must be an inverse. If one maps any element to 0, the product of the respresentation will be zero whereas the product of the representations must be the 1 element. Anyway, the 1 element of the group should be mapped on the unity in the representation space: $e\rightarrow 1$, which is impossible by attributing representations with the value 0.  This is on group level, in case of Lie-groups (continous groups, so $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is not a Lie-group)  Lie-algebra elements can indeed by mapped to 0. But  Lie-algebra and Lie-groups elements are very different.

Comment: Part of the representation property is also the mapping $e\rightarrow 1$.

Answer (score 0):

> Since in that both the elements are the same, but Isn't in the group the two elements can't be the same?

You seem to be conflating the notions of an element of a group and the matrix corresponding to that element in a certain representation of the group.

The group in question contains two distinct elements, $e$ and $g_1$. However, in certain specific representations (actually just one irrep in this example), the matrices representing distinct elements of a finite group can identical.

To keep track of whether you're talking about an element of a group or a matrix for that element in a particular representation, it is common to use notation more specific than "$e\rightarrow 1\ \ \ \&\ \ \ g_1\rightarrow -1$." It varies based on the text you're using, but for a representation $\Gamma$, you're likely to see something like "$\Gamma(e)=1\ \&\ \Gamma(g_1)=-1$".

It is not actually very surprising that the matrices for these two distinct elements are identical in a certain irrep: this simply means that there exists a basis in which the two transformations $g_1$ and $e$ act in the same manner. The example you chose is particularly convenient. Notice that if the group contains an identity operation ($e$) and a rotation of 180° around the $z$ axis ($g_1$), you have $g_1^2=e$ and the two irreps you mentioned in the question. If you consider the basis $\{z\}$, both operations are just identity operations.

A similar line of reasoning enables you to see that in the group, the identity operation is, in fact unique, despite the identity not being appearing only once in one of the irreps.

Comment: Does that mean the representation need not be following the properties of the group?

Comment: A (matrix) representation $D$ of a group $G$ needs to fulfill $D(g_1\cdot g_2)=D(g_1)\cdot D(g_2)$ for all group elements $g_1,g_2\in G$, where the dot between the $g$'s is the group operation, and the dot between the $D$'s is matrix multiplication. The trivial representation always fulfills this.

Comment: @Koschi So I suppose the answer to my question is "Yes".

Comment: A representation in which  only the group identity  element  maps to the identity matrix is said to be *faithful*. If a representation of $G$ is not faithful then the set  $H$ of group elements that map to the identity matrix is an invariant subgroup of $G$  and the representation is a faithful represenetation of the quotient group $G/H$.

Comment: @YoungKindaichi the answer to your question in [this comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/686987/#comment1537664_686992) is technically "no." The matrices that constitute a representation satisfy group properties (closure, existence of an identity, associativity, invertibility) with the binary operation of matrix multiplication. The uniqueness of the identity element of a group means that if there are multiple identity elements in the group, then they are all equal; the irreps follow this too.