# Does this group have a faithful unitary representation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

A group has just been implemented. It is easy to work with. Please see  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4498140/how-to-prove-that-a-unique-inverse-exists-for-every-element-of-this-group-like-s/4498165#4498165) before or after reading the summary below if you can.

Let $\mathbb{R^*} := \mathbb{R}$ \  $\{0\} $

Given the tuples (a,b,c,d) with a,b,d $\in \mathbb{R^*}$ and c $\in \mathbb{R}$.

$G_1 \times G_2 \times G_3 \times G_2$ with identity $(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_2) = (\frac{3}{2}, 1,-1,1)$ and inverse $(s,p,m,n)$ is $(\frac{9}{4s},\frac{1}{p}, -m-2 ,\frac{1}{n})$ where :

$G_1$ is the group with underlying set $\mathbb{R^*}$ and operation $a \cdot b = \frac{2}{3} ab$

$G_2$ is the multiplicative group of nonzero reals

$G_3$ is the group with underlying set $\mathbb{R}$ and operation $a \cdot b = a + b + 1$

Does this group have a faithful unitary representation?

My first approach to this was to stare at the group identity, inverse, and one or two elements and see if I can write down the matrix for the identity with certain properties, and then see that the products made sense.

My second approach was to try to follow the answer of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4350379/does-the-representation-of-the-group-also-follow-the-properties-of-the-group) post and answer. It suggests thinking in terms of $g_1 .g_2  \rightarrow L(g_1) L(g_2)$. If one faithful unitary representation could be just written down, then by example it has at least one unitary representation.

Comment: "Simple group" is a term of art. It means a group which is nontrivial and does not have any proper nontrivial normal subgroups. The group in your question is **not** a simple group. If you meant "simple" in its colloquial meaning, then break out the thesaurus and find a synonym which does not have a technical well-known meaning in this context. (Avoid "trivial" as well).

Comment: Every locally compact Hausdorff group admits a faithful continuous unitary representation, say, the left regular representation.

Comment: There should be a faithful representation into $GL_5(R)$, but you will not be able to do it with 4 dimensions because your matrix cannot be invertible.

Comment: The group you're talking about is just a very basic, easy-to-understand (relatively speaking) group that looks a little wonky because [transport of structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure) has been applied to obscure the formulas a bit. (Although I don't like how complicated that Wikipedia article makes transport of structure look at first glance.) This is not research-level at all and does not belong in a research journal. It perhaps belongs as a homework assignment, class project, or personal expository project. Also why are you so interested in this particular group?

Comment: Yes, I figured as much, and I am kind of treating it as a personal expository project at this point. My interest in this group is as a conduit to trying to understand the Heisenberg group. Also, as a much longer-term goal maybe someday I can understand what $SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)$ is all about. For now, though, I am just tinkering with this group. Also, it is the first group that I ever implemented.

Comment: I have deleted a very large number of comments on this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every group $G$ whatsoever has a faithful unitary representation on the [sequence space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space#%E2%84%93p_spaces) $\ell^2(G)$ (regarding $G$ as a discrete group with the discrete topology and the counting measure). I'm going to guess that what you really want to know is whether there is a faithful *finite-dimensional* unitary representation.

In general, if $G_1, G_2$ have faithful finite-dimensional unitary representations $\rho_i : G_i \to U(n_i)$, then $G_1 \times G_2$ has a faithful finite-dimensional unitary representation

$$\rho_1 \times \rho_2 : G_1 \times G_2 \to U(n_1) \times U(n_2) \hookrightarrow U(n_1 + n_2)$$

where the inclusion $\hookrightarrow$ is given by the direct sum, or concretely by block matrices. So the question reduces to asking whether each of the individual groups $G_i$ you've listed have faithful finite-dimensional unitary representations.

$G_1$ is just isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ and hence to $G_2$; the isomorphism sends $a \in G_1$ to $\frac{2}{3} a \in \mathbb{R}^{\times}$. Abstractly $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R} \times C_2$, which has a faithful $2$-dimensional unitary representation given by sending

$$(r, \pm) \mapsto \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \pm e^{i \alpha r} & 0 \\ 0 & \pm e^{i \beta r} \end{array} \right]$$

where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ are incommensurable, meaning that $\frac{\alpha}{\beta} \not \in \mathbb{Q}$; for example we could take $\alpha = 1, \beta = \pi$. This condition is equivalent to the representation being faithful (exercise).

$G_3$ is just isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$; the isomorphism sends $a \in G_3$ to $a + 1 \in \mathbb{R}$. The same representation as above works without the signs.

Altogether we get that the group you wrote down, which abstractly is $\mathbb{R}^4 \times C_2^3$, has an $8$-dimensional faithful unitary representation.

Comment: Just to be sure, what is  $C_2$

Comment: Is this the group of order 2, with {0,1} ?

Comment: I am struggling a bit with " $\mathbb{R^*}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R} \times C_2$"

Comment: @Kevin: yes, it's the cyclic group of order $2$, which you can think of as the group of signs $\{ \pm 1 \}$ under multiplication. The isomorphism sends a nonzero real number $r$ to the pair $(\log |r|, \text{sgn}(r))$ where $\text{sgn}(r) = \frac{r}{|r|}$.

Comment: Ah yes, it works with {$\pm 1$}